# Error on getting thumbnail_url field with Business Discovery API (Instagram Graph)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get thumbnail_url using Business Discovery API (LINK) and get an error.

[Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery) says: *You can use both nested requests and field expansion to get public fields for a Business or Creator Account's media objects.*

[image]

In [IGMedia docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media) says:  *thumbnail_url - Public*

[image]

So my working request:

```
{page-id}?fields=business_discovery.username(nike){media{media_url,media_type,children{media_url}}}.
```

Response:
[image]

And, if I add thumbnail_url field in request:

```
{page-id}?fields=business_discovery.username(nike){media{media_url,media_type,thumbnail_url,children{media_url}}}
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Please read documentation for supported fields.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A2sUKUDWUyAJjyQErkGjx7b"
  }
}
```

It’s not the end. If I add thumbnail_url in children expansion, from response disappears all CAROUSEL_ALBUM posts.

Request:

```
{page-id}?fields=business_discovery.username(nike){media{media_url,media_type,children{media_url,thumbnail_url}}}
```

Response:
[image]

So my questions:
Is it a bug (seems like that it)? Or docs are not updated?
Is there other official way to get thumbnail_url using Business Discovery API?

Sorry about long read :)

Comment: The first errors is likely due to the fact, that you got other media types than just VIDEO in the result. Whether it is an _error_ on Facebook's part, to not simply ignore a requested field, when an object type doesn't have it - well that's an issue you'd have to take up with them.

Comment: @CBroe when i getting media with media endpoint, i don't have that errors. I reported that issue to them as a bug. Thank you!